# making an div changes it background when mouse hover using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello there i'm doing an course about **JavaScript** in the first exercise they ask to make a button that creates boxes,and in the second exercise they ask to use an function to when the mouse hover over the boxes they change color randomly, but i didn't manged to do it so here's firstly the box maker:

```html
<body>
    <button>CREATE</button>
    <p>BOXES GENERATOR</p>
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

```js
      var button1 = document.querySelector("button");

      button1.onclick = function() {
        var cubeElement = document.createElement("div");
        cubeElement.setAttribute("class", "bt");

        var bodyElement = document.querySelector(".container");
        bodyElement.appendChild(cubeElement);

        var cubestyleElement = document.querySelectorAll(".bt");
        for (var i = 0; i < cubestyleElement.length; i++) {
          cubestyleElement[i].setAttribute(
            "style",
            "background: #850900; height: 100px; width: 100px; border: solid #000 2px;"
          );
        }
      };
```

and there's the function to make it change colors randomly:

```js
function getRandomColor() {
           var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
           var color = "#";
           for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
             color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
           }
           return color;
         };
         var newColor = getRandomColor(); // #E943F0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
function getRandomColor() {
           var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
           var color = "#";
           for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
             color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
           }
           return color;
         };
        
var i = 0;
var button1 = document.querySelector("button");

      button1.onclick = function() {
        var cubeElement = document.createElement("div");
        cubeElement.setAttribute("class", "bt");

        var bodyElement = document.querySelector(".container");
        bodyElement.appendChild(cubeElement);

        var cubestyleElement = document.querySelectorAll(".bt");
        for (i; i < cubestyleElement.length; i++) {
        var element = cubestyleElement[i];
          element.setAttribute(
            "style",
            "background: #850900; height: 100px; width: 100px; border: solid #000 2px;"
          );
          element.onmouseover = function(){
           var newColor = getRandomColor(); 
          element.setAttribute(
            "style",
            "background:"+ newColor+"; height: 100px; width: 100px; border: solid #000 2px;"
          );
          }
        }
      };
```

```html
<button>CREATE</button>
    <p>BOXES GENERATOR</p>
    <div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please check this..** Are you looking this?

```js
var button1 = document.querySelector("button");

      button1.onclick = function() {
        var cubeElement = document.createElement("div");
        cubeElement.setAttribute("class", "bt");
        
        cubeElement.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
          event.target.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
        });
        
        var bodyElement = document.querySelector(".container");
        bodyElement.appendChild(cubeElement);

        var cubestyleElement = document.querySelectorAll(".bt");
        for (var i = 0; i < cubestyleElement.length; i++) {
          cubestyleElement[i].setAttribute(
            "style",
            "background: #850900; height: 100px; width: 100px; border: solid #000 2px;"
          );
        }
      };

function getRandomColor() {
           var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
           var color = "#";
           for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
             color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
           }
           return color;
};
```

```html
<body>
    <button>CREATE</button>
    <p>BOXES GENERATOR</p>
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: It's not exactly this, the objective is when i put the mouse pointer over these boxes they start to change the color randomly. Anyways thanks!

Comment: the only problem is that in your code when i press the create button it resets the color.

Comment: I intentionally did that, you don't want to this? :)

Comment: thanks but what i mean is to not reset all the boxes colors when pressing the create button, like in the Leonardo's code